# Responsive design not working on actual smart phones

Tags: android, ios, css, responsive-design, smartphone

We have programmed a site at: http://tcsdesignreno.com/zing-cards/ to be responsive. Whenever I check it in online responsive design test sites (such as: http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ or http://beta.screenqueri.es/) it looks fine but if I bring it up on my HTC Sensation, iPhone 5 or a Galaxy 3 it cuts off the right side of the screen. I have used the standard web browsers and chrome on the phones. I am not sure how to check the CSS on my phone to see what the problem is.

Does anyone have any suggestions on either how to fix the site or how to find the error from my phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can debug Android's Chrome Browser from your computer; details at [this link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).

Comment: Thank you both, I got this to work but I still can't find the problem. It seems to think that it is 360px wide but doesn't show at that width. You can see a screenshot here: http://tcsdesignreno.com/zing-cards/Zing-Cards_mobile.png. I don't have any margins or set widths that should make it do this. I am using a child theme of the twenty-thirteen theme in wordpress.